# Need to scheduled an SSRS report to save to a SharePoint document library

Tags: sharepoint, ssrs-2008

I want to schedule an SSRS subscription to save directly to a SharePoint document library and I can't.  I get the error **"Failure writing file \server\path\report.pdf: Access to the path '\server\path\report.pdf' is denied.**

Here are the facts:
  - I get a different error if I use the user/pass combo for the subscription, so I know my user/pass is correct
  - I can save to all other shared file areas I have tried
  - I can log into the SSRS server and map to the SP UNC path and write documents to it
  - unlike other mappings I've done on the SSRS server, the SP directory does not stay mapped, even though I have clicked 'reconnect at login'
  - SSRS Server is Win 2008; SP is 2008 (I think)
  - we have turned on WEBDAV and installed Desktop Experience
  - SP integrated mode is not an option

Any ideas or nudges in a general direction are greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If installing SSRS in SharePoint integrated mode is not an option, then you will need to write custom code.

Set the SSRS subscription to write out to a local path on the SQL server, and then set a recurring scheduled task to run your custom .exe.

The custom .exe should copy the contents of a local directory to a given SharePoint document library. The .net SharePoint objects make this pretty easy: you'll probably spend more time getting the project set up than writing code to copy the files.

Answer (score 1):

I got it to work by

- Enabling WEBDAV
- Turning Desktop Experience mode on
- Mapping the Http file connect path that sharepoint gives to as a drive

For some reason when i did that it gave me the ability to write directly to the sharepoint folder on the server. \sharepoint-server\sites\path\shared documents\

Comment: I also got it to work this way. Enable WebDav, then adding a WebClient Parameter of AuthForwardServerList, listing the site, and giving permissions in sharepoint to the service account running SQL Agent.

Answer (score 0):

Hi try configuring the centeral admin first 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb326213.aspx

then follow the following post to configure delivery to sharepoint library

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb283186.aspx

Comment: Thanks, Ashutosh, but integrated mode is not an option.  Any other ideas?